# Issue with fetching data from excel (Using Java)

Tags: java, excel

I have a problem with getting data from this function when I call it twice. The function returns an arrayList of all rows fetched from an excel sheet. When I call the function the first time I get the correct amount of rows (all rows except the headline row and the row with exit). The second time I call the function I get 0.

It seems that something happens with file or the sheets created the second time, here is the code:

```
private static List<String[]> getDataFromXLS(String excelPath) {

    FileInputStream fis;
    Workbook workbook; Sheet sheet; XSSFRow row;
    Iterator<Row> rows; 
    XSSFCell cell; 
    List<String[]> allExcelRows = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String[] xlsRow;
    columnNames = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
    paramNames = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    int totalColumnCount = 0;
    int rowNumber = 1;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(new File(excelPath));
        workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
        sheet = workbook.getSheet("TestData");
        rows = sheet.rowIterator();

        while (rows.hasNext()) {        

            row = ((XSSFRow) rows.next());
            if (rowNumber == 1) {
                //based on amount of parameters on first xls row
                totalColumnCount = row.getLastCellNum();
            }

            xlsRow = new String[totalColumnCount];

            //check which column is TestType
            //iterate through all the columns
            for (int columnNumber=0; columnNumber<totalColumnCount; columnNumber++) {

                cell = row.getCell(columnNumber, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK); 
                if (getCellValue(cell).trim().toLowerCase().trim().equals("testtype") ){
                    testTypeColumnIndex = columnNumber; //this is Testtype index
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (rowNumber != 1) {                   
                for(int columnNumber=0; columnNumber<totalColumnCount; columnNumber++) {
                    cell = row.getCell(columnNumber, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);                    

                    //read only rows before exit
                    if (columnNumber == testTypeColumnIndex && getCellValue(cell).trim().toLowerCase().trim().equals("exit") ){
                        reachedExit = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    xlsRow[columnNumber] = getCellValue(cell).trim();
                }

                //reached exit?
                if (reachedExit) {
                    break; 
                }
                allExcelRows.add(xlsRow);
            } else {
                //save column names into map
                for(int columnNumber=0; columnNumber<totalColumnCount; columnNumber++) {
                    cell = row.getCell(columnNumber, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);                                                                     
                    columnNames.put(columnNumber, getCellValue(cell).trim());
                    paramNames.put(getCellValue(cell).trim(), columnNumber);
                }
            }
            rowNumber++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    fis.close();
    return allExcelRows;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am taking a bit of a guess here but I think the problem is that the `reachedExit` class level boolean is not reset at the start of the method. Hence when you call it the second time this code block executes:

```
//reached exit?
if (reachedExit) {
    break; 
}
```

....meaning that nothing gets added to `allExcelRows`

Comment: You're welcome. Could you accept the answer to indicate that it resolved your problem, please?

Comment: Sorry how do I do that?

Comment: Just click on the grey tick below the bottom of the two arrows on the top left of the answer